# What is the problem with "onSubmit" function in Formik?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, formik

I am creating a form with Formik in React. The code is following:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { StyledFormControl } from '../addTodo/styles';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import { textFields } from '../../../utils/staticData/constants';
import { routes, labels } from '../../../utils/staticData/enums';
import { UsersData } from '../../../utils/interfaces/users';
import { DialogStructure } from '../common/DialogStructure';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import DialogActions from '../common/DialogActions';

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  closeDialog: () => void;
}

interface FormData {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

export const AddUserDialog:React.FC<Props> = ({ open, closeDialog }) => {
  const initialValues: FormData = {name: '', email: ''};

  const [ users, setUsers ] = useState<UsersData[]>([]);

  const validate = (values: FormData) => {
    const errors: FormData = {name: '', email: ''};
    const { name, email } = values;
    if(!email) {
      errors.email = 'Email is required';
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(email)) {
      errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
    }
    if(!name) {
      errors.name = 'Username is required';
    } else if(users.map(user => user.user_name).includes(name)) {
      errors.name = 'Username is already taken';
    }
    return errors;
  }

  const confirm = (values: FormData, {setSubmitting}: any) => {
    axios.post(`${routes.server}/${routes.users}`, {
      user_name: values.name,
      email: values.email
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${routes.server}/${routes.users}`, {
      params: {
        without_pagination: true
      }
    }).then(res => {
      setUsers(res.data);
    });
  }, [ open ]);

  return(
    <DialogStructure
      open={open}
      title='Add user'
      action='Add'
      close={closeDialog}
      confirm={() => true}
    >
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={validate}
        onSubmit={confirm}
      >
        {({values, errors, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleSubmit}) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <StyledFormControl fullWidth>
              {Boolean(errors.name) && <FormHelperText error={true}>{errors.name}</FormHelperText> }
              <TextField
                type='text'
                name='name'
                value={values.name}
                label={labels.user}
                variant='outlined'
                fullWidth
                inputProps={{ maxLength: textFields.user.maxLength }}
                onChange={handleChange}
                error={Boolean(errors.name)}
              />
              <FormHelperText>Symbols: {values.name.length}/{textFields.user.maxLength}</FormHelperText>
            </StyledFormControl>

            <StyledFormControl fullWidth>
              {Boolean(errors.email) && <FormHelperText error={true}>{errors.email}</FormHelperText> }
              <TextField
                type='email'
                name='email'
                value={values.email}
                label={labels.email}
                variant='outlined'
                fullWidth
                onChange={handleChange}
                error={Boolean(errors.email)}
              />
            </StyledFormControl>
            <DialogActions 
              close={closeDialog}
              confirm={handleSubmit}
              action='Add'
              isInvalid={Boolean(validate(values).email) || Boolean(validate(values).name)}
            />
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </DialogStructure>
  );
}
```

Here is `DialogActions` component, where submit button is located:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

interface Props {
  close: () => void;
  confirm: () => void;
  action: string;
  isInvalid: boolean;
}
const DialogActions:React.FC<Props> = ({close, confirm, action, isInvalid}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={close}>
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button type='submit' variant='contained' color='secondary' disabled={isInvalid}>
        { action }
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default DialogActions;
```

I wrote this code according to Formik official docs. Here is [link](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview#the-gist).
And "onSubmit" function (aka "confirm") isn't working. Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing>

Comment: Whoops... Edited

Comment: When you say not working, do you mean its not invoking or its not using correct values

Comment: Its not invoking